# What happened to the custom theory solver methods in the Z3 API?

Tags: z3

I have been reading Nikolai's article on Engineering Theories with Z3 for how to interface a custom decision procedure with Z3. In there several methods such as AssertTheoryAxiom, NewAssignment, and FinalCheck etc are mentioned. However I have been unable to locate them in the most recent (new?) Z3 API at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/namespace_microsoft_1_1_z3.html. Could someone let me know where they or their replacements are? 
2. On a related note I see several new concepts in the interface such as Probes and Tactics. Are these described or explained anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The interface for custom decision procedure is currently deprecated. They can still be used with the old solver API. See the following posts for additional information:

- [Using theory plugins with solvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587101/using-theory-plugins-with-solvers)
- [Custom simplifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802651/custom-simplifiers)

[Here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/deprecated.html#_deprecated000021) is the full list of deprecated APIs.
Regarding tactics and probes, see [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/strategy.pdf), and the Z3 tutorials ([Python](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies) and [SMT 2.0](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies)) about it.