# Z3 Theory Plugins splitting to sub-problems

Tags: z3

Sometimes (or many times) it happens are that the problems are so big that there much time-outs with the Z3 solver. In such cases, I think that it will be beneficial to split the problem into smaller sub-problems.

I wanted to ask specifically about the `Theory Plugins` in Z3.

Suppose that I have 3 variables `A,B and C`. And I am assigning values to each of them.
Suppose due to some constraints that I specified, the values that are assigned are `A=0` and `B=1`. Now, depending on these values of `A and B`, `C` is calculated with another set of equations, probably which are not encoded as constraints. In that case, is it possible to write a theory plugin which will say that when `A and B` are allocated certain values, then callback to some functions to return the value of `C`.

I saw a theory example in the examples directory, however it is not very clear for me. Also I tried to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theory plugins are not the ideal technology for splitting a problem into sub-problems. A theory plugin is usually defined when we want to extend the set of theories supported by Z3. For example, suppose we want to include a module that can reason about strings. This module would provide new interpreted symbols such as: `substring`, `contains`, etc. 
[This article](http://lara.epfl.ch/~psuter/articles/SuterETAL11SetsWithCardinalityConstraints.pdf) describes a decision procedure for sets + cardinality constraints. This procedure was implemented as a theory plugin for Z3.

That being said, the theory plugins are currently deprecated. They are still supported in Z3, but they are incompatible with the new Solver API. To use plugins, we have to use the older (deprecated) API.

Here are some related posts that describe the current state of the theory plugin API in Z3:

- [Using theory plugins with solvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587101/using-theory-plugins-with-solvers)
- [What happened to the custom theory solver methods in the Z3 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048498/what-happened-to-the-custom-theory-solver-methods-in-the-z3-api/14049024#14049024)