# What parts of the Z3 C++ API are still supported?

Tags: c++, z3

I see some of the Z3 API is marked deprecated.  I also see some comments by Leonardo that more of the API was retired in 2012 (related: [contexts are in maintenance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587101/using-theory-plugins-with-solvers/13620921#13620921)).  What parts of the API should I be using?

Is [this page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html) a good guide to the active parts of the C API?  Same for [this page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__cppapi.html) and C++?

I think I'm just looking for two yes's from someone in the know, but if it's more nuanced then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some parts of the C API were marked as deprecated. They are listed in [this page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/deprecated.html#_deprecated000027).
Two relevant groups are: the theory plugin API, and the old solver API.